# Python: Repeat a 2d array K number of times and transform

Tags: python, numpy

I have the 2d array `XTM` below.

```
array([[-0.49349673, -0.16749763,  1.09365913,  0.91916602,  0.5942118 ],
       [-1.1357679 , -1.06851897, -0.72537699,  0.06350472,  0.1747241 ],
       [-0.29972989, -0.3321334 , -1.52296231, -1.41765091, -0.53735561]])
```

I have the following to repeat the entire matrix K number of times and expand to the right. i.e. 
`np.tile(XTM,(1,K))`, as follow:

```
[XTM]   -> [XTM   2nd XTM ... ... K_th XTM]
```

However, when I try to reshape the matrix to a 3d array such that it becomes below, it fails.

I tried `np.tile(XTM,(1,K)).reshape(K,3,5)` but it doesn't give me what i want.

This is what i want ultimately

```
XTM3d[0] = XTM
XTM3d[1] = XTM
     .
     .
     .
XTM3d[K] = XTM
```

Comment: You can keep using `np.tile` just with different dimension: `np.tile(XTM, (k,1,1))` should work as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html), specifying the final shape (`a` being the input array):

```
k = 2
out = np.broadcast_to(a, (k, *a.shape))
```

---

```
out.shape
# (2, 3, 5)

print(out)
[[[-0.49349673 -0.16749763  1.09365913  0.91916602  0.5942118 ]
  [-1.1357679  -1.06851897 -0.72537699  0.06350472  0.1747241 ]
  [-0.29972989 -0.3321334  -1.52296231 -1.41765091 -0.53735561]]

 [[-0.49349673 -0.16749763  1.09365913  0.91916602  0.5942118 ]
  [-1.1357679  -1.06851897 -0.72537699  0.06350472  0.1747241 ]
  [-0.29972989 -0.3321334  -1.52296231 -1.41765091 -0.53735561]]]
```